# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) while sending byte[]

Tags: android, web-services, socketexception

I am trying to upload video recorded through android mobile. but while sending video as byte[] to server I am getting below error :

```
  01-20 13:03:18.250: E/SaveMedia-response(4393): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

Here is how I am trying to upload video :

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                HelpMeConstant.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "SaveMedia");
        Log.i("SaveMedia-parameter", "Email : " + Email + ", Media : " + Media
                + "MediaType : " + MediaType + ",MediaExt : " + MediaExt);

        MediaAvidance mediainfo = new MediaAvidance();
        mediainfo.EmailId = Email;
        mediainfo.Media = Media;
        mediainfo.MediaExt = MediaExt;
        mediainfo.MediaType = MediaType;

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("mediainfo");
        pi.setValue(mediainfo);
        pi.setType(mediainfo.getClass());

        request.addProperty(pi);
/*      request.addProperty("EmailId",Email);
         request.addProperty("Media", Media); 
         request.addProperty("MediaType", MediaType);
         request.addProperty("MediaExtn", MediaExt);
*/       
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.i("SaveMedia","Serialising..");
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                HelpMeConstant.SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;

        try {
            Log.i("SaveMedia","Calling service..");
            httpTransport.call(HelpMeConstant.SOAP_ACTION + "SaveMedia",
                    envelope);
            Log.i("SaveMedia","getting response..");
            response = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            response = exception.toString();
        }
        Log.i("response", response.toString());
        return response.toString();
```

and it is sending to a .net web service which is as below :

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string SaveMedia(MediaAvidance avidanceinfo)
    {
        rs = new ResultSet();
        rs = logictask.SaveMedia(avidanceinfo.EmailId,avidanceinfo.Media,avidanceinfo.MediaType,avidanceinfo.MediaExt);
        return rs.isSuccessfull;
    }
```

MediaAvidance :

```
public class MediaAvidance implements KvmSerializable {
    public String EmailId;
    public byte[] Media;
    public String MediaType;
    public String MediaExt;

    public MediaAvidance() {
    }

    public MediaAvidance(String EmailID, byte[] Media, String MediaType,
            String MediaExt) {

        this.EmailId = EmailID;
        this.Media = Media;
        this.MediaType = MediaType;
        this.MediaExt = MediaExt;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
        case GETEMAILID:
            return EmailId;
        case GETMEDIA:
            return Media;
        case GETMEDIATYPE:
            return MediaType;
        case GETMEDIAEXT:
            return MediaExt;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "EmailId";
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
            info.name = "Media";
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "MediaType";
            break;
        case 3:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "MediaExt";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            EmailId = value.toString();
            break;
        case 1:
            Media = (byte[]) value;
            break;
        case 2:
            MediaType = value.toString();
            break;
        case 3:
            MediaExt = value.toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

At server side MediaAvidance class donot implement `KvmSerializable` and its method.

I searched for few days and gone through many question in stackoverflow & understood that i am trying to write when the connection is closed and also that it is something related to socket programming. BUT

I don't know how to keep connection alive(probably a solution I think).
Please help me.

Thanks,
Sourabh

Comment: can you provide more lines from your server error trace here.And can you paste MediaAvidance class here.

Comment: MediaAvidance class code is added. I haven't got any stack trace in exception. that was all I have as exception.

Comment: In your client code, you are taking that video as byte array then passing it into your soap request, i think. Most probably due to large size of byte array, your server or client connection is getting closed before completion of upload.May be keep this connection alive for few minutes your file gets upload.You can search for it. May be, you won't solve your problem by implementing it on client side only.If you have control over server then for the test first try to upload a picture with few bytes, if it successfully uploaded then we can confirm your exact issue here.

Comment: when I tried using same process with 18kb image I got different error as : `01-20 17:35:40.579: E/SaveDocument-response(13412): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Method HelpMe.SaveMedia can not be reflected. ---> The XML element 'SaveMedia' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41df97b0`

Comment: I got this now:
'01-20 18:43:05.639: E/SaveMedia(16211): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41dfc560
01-20 18:43:05.639: E/SaveMedia(16211):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
01-20 18:43:05.639: E/SaveMedia(16211):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)'


at line 'httpTransport.call' '\n'


if you can help Now

Comment: you are not passing some value in request now. replcae you code with existing one in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Managed to get it work. posting this solution hoping it will be usefull for someone like me. You could have more or any of below problem in you code, but I am happy to make these 3 mistakes, and learn from them, that was causing problem in video upload :

1. I have serialized `MediaAvidance` in android by implementing `KvmSerializable` but in order to get it worked your server side `MediaAvidance` must also be serialized. that I have done by below code which solved my `Cannot Serialize` Exception I was getting :

```
   [Serializable]
   public class MediaAvidance
```

you also need to register your `SoapSerializationEnvelope`to `MarshalBase64` :

```
   envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
```

1. when you call from android, set exact same name in `PropertyInfo` as you have in service method parameter(ex : avidanceinfo), this one solved `faultstring: 'Server was unable to read request.` exception :

   property name defined in android

   ```
   pi.setName("avidanceinfo");
   ```

   service method :

   ```
    [WebMethod]
    public string SaveMedia(MediaAvidance avidanceinfo)
   ```
2. At last your need to add
   `envelope.implicitTypes = true ;`
   so that `HttpTransportSE` will be able to recognise `MediaAvidance` type at server else you will get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when using xs:anyType....` Exception.

**Hope this may be helpfull to you. :) **